# Pre-generate Graphics object to improve printing performance

Tags: c#, performance, printing

I have an application that prints invoices.  I'd like to be able to pre-generate the invoices in a background task/process so I can reduce the downtime required to send the document to the printer when prompted by the user or other automation events.  I'm looking for something like this...

```
Graphics _g;

// background task would call this method
void GenerateInvoice(Invoice i)
{
  _g = ???? // ????
  _g.DrawImage...
  _g.DrawString....
}

// user action, or automation event, would call this method...
void PrintInvoice()
{
  if (_g == null) 
    throw new DocumentNotPreparedException();

  PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
  pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "My Fast Printer";
  pd.PrintPage += PrintHandler;
  pd.Print();
}

void PrintHandler(object o, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
  // ????
  e.Graphics = _g;
}
```

Any suggestions on what needs to be done in and around the '???' sections?

Comment: The `Graphics` object doesn't contain anything, really. If you don't mind losing the vectorised data (which may affect performance and quality), just render to a bitmap and then render this bitmap in your `PrintHandler`. For best quality, ensure the bitmap has the same DPI as the printer.

Comment: @Luaan you mean do something like this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404307(v=vs.110).aspx ?

Comment: Yeah. That's a simple and not production-ready example, but it shows the basic idea. You can then use `e.Graphics.DrawImage` to paint the whole bitmap at once in your print handler.

Comment: @Luaan Thanks.  I'll look into it.  Is there a "better" way to generate/print documents than using PrintDocument?

Comment: My crystal ball says that you have not used a profiler to discover the slow code in your existing program.  And that after a couple of weeks of writing difficult and risky code you'll find out that you accomplished nothing.  But you'll be a much smarter programmer afterwards, that's useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to be able to pre-generate the invoices in a background task/process so I can reduce the downtime required to send the document to the printer

First step is to make sure you know what the source of the "downtime" is. It would be unusual for the bottleneck to exist in your own program's rendering code. Most often, a major source of printer slowness is either in the print driver itself (e.g. a driver with a lot of code and data that has to be paged in to handle the job), or dealing with a printer that requires client-side rasterization of the page images (which requires lots of memory to support the high-resolution bitmaps needed, which in turn can be slow on some machines, and of course greatly increases the time spent sending those rasterized images to the printer, over whatever connection you're using).

If and when you've determined it's your own code that's slow, and after you've also determined that your own code is fundamentally as efficient as you can make it, *then* you might consider pre-rendering as a way of improving the user experience. You have two main options here: rendering into a bitmap, and rendering into a [metafile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.metafile(v=vs.110).aspx).

Personally, I would recommend the latter. A metafile will preserve your original rendering commands, providing a resolution-independent and memory-efficient representation of your printing data. This would be particularly valuable if your output consists primarily of line-drawings and text output.

If you render into a bitmap instead, you will want to make sure you allocate a bitmap at least the same resolution as that being supported by the printer for your print job. Otherwise, you will lose significant image quality in the process and your printouts will not look very good. Note though that if you go this route, you run the risk of incurring the same sort of memory-related slowdown that would theoretically be an issue when dealing with the printer driver directly.

Finally, in terms of choosing between the two techniques, one scenario in which the bitmap approach might be preferable to the metafile approach is if your print job output consists primarily of a large number of bitmaps which are already at or near the resolution supported by the printer. In this case, flattening those bitmaps into a single page-sized bitmap could actually *reduce* the memory footprint. Drawing them into a metafile would require each individual bitmap to be stored in the metafile, and if the total size of those bitmaps is larger than the single page-sized bitmap, that would of course use even more memory. Flattening them into a single bitmap would allow you to avoid having a large number of individual, large bitmaps in memory all at once.

But really, the above is mostly theoretical. You're suggesting adding a great level of complexity to your printing code, in order to address a problem that is most likely not one you can solve in the first place, because the problem most likely does not lie in your own code at all. You should make sure you've examined very carefully the reason for slow printing, before heading down this path.

Comment: I have looked into the issue further.  Rendering does take sometime, but I see ways in which I can pre-generate some items (barcodes, etc.).  I discovered the real bottleneck was in the creation of creating a new PrintDocument for each invoice.  Once I started re-using the PrintDocument instance the previous 2-3 second delay dropped to almost zero (as determined using StopWatch).